# SNMP/MIB trace values and statistics

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

Which method is best to iterate keys in a snmpwalk? I need to find statistics for network in different boards in different PCs. Linux and Windows. I understand that the 1.3.1..... is different. How can I do something like "snmp fetch eth0 mrtu value" ? or "snmp fetch dsk "D" free%" ?

Should I open every mib under mibs directory and trackdown every meaningfull or meaningless key that is "dsk" or "net" and give it a try? And what value suits for me, keep it aside?

Or is there a 'rightful' method ?
I need to make a code working on java but yet I don't possess the knowledge yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under MIBII you've got standard MIBs in which you can find useful informations about Disk an Interfaces. You can study these MIBS and write the code that get back just the necessaries counters. I think that it could be a bit different from Windows to Linux but not so. A "snmp fetch eth0 mrtu value" has sense if you are sure eth0 exists on the remote computer, so you'd better discover things and then poll them.

Remember that :

A SnmpWalk (as pointed by @bstPierre) is no more than multiple SNMP-GETNEXT/SNMP-RESPONSE so it as a cost on the bandwith, and the result is not so easy to compute.

With a simple SNMP-GET/SNMP-RESPONSE you can retreive multiple counters.

Comment: I suppose...this is the way that the future "auto-discover" is also implemented in various products ?

Comment: You are right, but in SNMP "auto-discover" just bring you back a tree of typed datas, if you don't have the associate MIB on the client it has not got many sense.

Comment: Ok. What I try now do, is to collect the interdependencies. For example I see that hrDeviceType, has hrDeviceProcessor or hrDeviceNetwork or or or...all this if I collect could I be able to make a tree of the dependent object and acquire values after? Is it right again this approach? I am thinking perhaps this approach is inadequate for example in case of windows and linux mashines.

Comment: Not sure to really understand what you want to do. But what is usally done is that the client discover which kind of SNMP host is on a given adress (with system MIB) and then just pick the needed counters.

Comment: Right!this is the key now. As far as I understand, in order to  collect the needed counters for different machines, I have to do something like this: Simple example. Checking sysDescr I see Windows or Linux. In java code I would write " You got Windows, then you have enum_WINDOWS. You got Linux? you got enum_LINUX. And when you got QNX, then just enum_UNKNOWN. Did you find hrDeviceProcessor, then dig in hrProcessorTable, iterate the values". Is this best approach ?

Answer (score 1):

To walk the MIB, use the SNMP GETNEXT operation. Do it repeatedly to perform a MIB walk.

See [this example for snmp4j](http://techdive.in/snmp/snmp4j-snmp-get-next-example).